# Call back method for Native Apple Maps

Tags: ios, apple-maps

Im using the Native Map for directions in my app using the following code:

```
 [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude, self.data.lat,self.data.long]]];
```

Is there a Callback scheme to return back to the app? Similar to `Googles` `comgooglemaps-x-callback`. It doesnt seem to be in the `Apple` docs so Im unsure whether its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Apple Maps does not have a scheme to return to the calling app. Google uses [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com), which Apple Maps does not support.